# angular2-jwt: No provider for AuthConfig

Tags: angular, ionic2, auth0

Im tying to use the `angular2-jwt` with my `ionic2` application and I keep getting `No provider for AuthConfig!`

Here is my `app.ts`:

```
import {AuthHttp, AuthConfig} from 'angular2-jwt';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http'
@App({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
  config: {}, // http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/
  providers: [
     provide(AuthHttp, {
      useFactory: (http) => {
        return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig(), http);
      },
      deps: [Http]
     }),
    AuthHttp
  ]
})
```

And im using that on my `login.ts` page:

```
import {AuthHttp, AuthConfig} from 'angular2-jwt';
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/login/login.html',
  directives: [IONIC_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class LoginPage {
     constructor(private authHttp: AuthHttp){
     }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's strange that you define twice the provider for `AuthConfig`:

```
providers: [
  provide(AuthHttp, {
    useFactory: (http) => {
      return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig(), http);
    },
    deps: [Http]
   }),
  AuthHttp // <-----------
]
```

The second will override the first one and expect `AuthConfig` to be injected in `AuthHttp` as first parameter. But there is no provider for `AuthConfig`.

It should work by removing the second `AuthHttp`, as described below:

```
providers: [
  provide(AuthHttp, {
    useFactory: (http) => {
      return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig(), http);
    },
    deps: [Http]
  })
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `AuthConfig` as a dependency :

```
import {AuthHttp, AuthConfig} from 'angular2-jwt';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http'
@App({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
  config: {}, // http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/
  providers: [
     provide(AuthHttp, {
      useFactory: (http) => {
        return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig(), http);
      },
      deps: [Http,AuthConfig]
     }),
    AuthHttp
  ]
})
```

Comment: Still the same, `no provider for AuthConfig`